# Ansible aws_ec2 inventory plugin - dynamic boto_profile

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am using the aws_ec2 inventory plugin and would like to pass the boto_profile in as a var at runtime.

I am trying to run the following command:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars profile=foo`

Inside my `aws_ec2.yml` plugin file I have:

`boto_profile: "{{ profile }}"`

This returns the error:

`The config profile ({{ profile }}) could not be found`

I am able to use the `profile` var inside my playbook. I am using the `ec2` module with `profile: "{{ profile }}"` That seems to work if I define a static inventory.

Is it possible to pass the `profile` var into the dynamic inventory file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja2 templates are not applicable to inventory *configuration* files.

Use environment variable `AWS_PROFILE` or `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` to set profile at runtime.

Like: `AWS_PROFILE=foo ansible-playbook playbook.yml`

Comment: Bummer. I am running a docker image, I don't think I can set the env var at run time.

Comment: Is there a reason templates are not available inside config files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in GitLab CI/CD and had the same issue, however you can look up the env variables in the dynamic inventory like this:

```
plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2
aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env','AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env','AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
regions:
    - eu-central-1
groups:
    webservers: "'app-server' in tags.Type"
```

and I cen set this up in the CI/CD under variables: and this is passed to docker container.