# Is there any way to use environmental variables inside Ansible's AWS dynamic inventory file (aws_ec2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I'd like to use an environmental variable inside aws_ec2 inventory file for the simple case of being able to easily separate different environments. Let's take this configuration as an example:

```
plugin: aws_ec2

filters:
  #tag:Cust_code: "01"
  tag:Cust_code: "{{ lookup('env','CUSTOMER_CODE') }}"
```

While the first line works (commented out), the second obviously doesn't and an empty host list is returned:

```
$ export CUSTOMER_CODE="01"
$ echo $CUSTOMER_CODE
01
$ ansible-inventory -i inventory/aws_ec2.yaml --graph
@all:
  |--@aws_ec2:
  |--@ungrouped:
```

I've read that the reason is because jinja2 templates are not supported in inventory files, even though they seem to work for some specific parameters according to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72241930/19407408 .

I don't want to use dynamic inventory script because I feel it might be too complicated and I don't understand the official documentation for it. I also would prefer not to use different inventory files for different environments as I already have to use 2 different inventory files for the same environment (because for some hosts I need to use "ansible_host: private_ip_address" via compose and for jumphosts I can't). Although the latter will have to be the solution if there's no better alternative.

Has anyone been able to come up with a clever solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `filters:` (and its `exclude_filters:` and `include_filters:` siblings) are not jinja2 aware. The good thing about ansible being open source is that one can see under the hood how things work:

- [`_query`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/blob/4.0.0/plugins/inventory/aws_ec2.py#L826) applies the include and exclude filters

  - [`ansible_dict_to_boto3_filter_list`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/blob/4.0.0/plugins/module_utils/transformation.py#L36) merely pivots the `tag:Name=whatever` over to `[{"Name":"tag:Name","Values":["whatever"]}]` format that boto wants, without further touching the key nor the values
  - [`_get_instances_by_region`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/blob/4.0.0/plugins/inventory/aws_ec2.py#L537) just calls `describe-instances` with those filters, again, without involving jinja2

Depending on how many instances the unfiltered list contains, using `groups:` or `keyed_groups:` may be an option along with a parameterized `- hosts:` in your playbook (e.g. `- hosts: cust_code{{ CUSTOMER_CODE }}`)

Otherwise, I'd guess your best bet would be to use [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) in a separate play in the playbook, since that allows you to have almost unlimited customization:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - add_host: ...
    groups:
    - cust_code_machines

- hosts: cust_code_machines
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="off to the races"
```

Comment: Thank you! While I could not find out how to make add_host work for my case, I did come up with a solution using `keyed_groups:`. I already was using `groups:` to get the exact host groups I needed, now I added `- key: tags.Cust_code` under keyed_groups. And inside the playbook file, I could make sure that the custom groups I added will only contain hosts that are also in the specified customer_code group like this: `- hosts: group1:&customer_code_{{ lookup('env', 'CUSTOMER_CODE') }}`. Now if only I could figure out how to get different groups to use different ansible_host values.